# Parsing XML from URL which doesn't have specific styling

Tags: xml, selenium-webdriver, jdom-2

I am trying to read the response using Selenium to perform some validations, and when the XML is displayed, There is info on the top of web page: "
The XML file appears to have any style information associated with it!" , I am trying to read the xml using JDOM2 and getting the error message "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 50; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId." , how to over come it!

Comment: 1. Have you considered using some other tool other than selenium in order to get XML from your website?  Maybe it'll be easier to request XML element using simple GET method using apache httpclient

2. Mind to provide XML sample? It seems that your XML file is not in correct format

Comment: I am using JDOM2 API for parsing, unfortunately I cant provide the sample, as it is from thrid party site and I believe that there is a problem in rendering the xml in FF. I will sure try with apache httpclient, and post you back! Thanks